# iPhone 4s is giving me trouble, can someone help me troubleshoot?

Tags: iphone

I thought my Hotmail account that I use my for my Apple ID was deleted but it was not. In the mean time I created a new Apple ID using the wrong e-mail. I never verified the new e-mail but its popping up on my iPhone everytime I try to update certain apps, even when I go to my SoundCloud I can't seem to find the fake e-mail. However it pops up when I try to update certain apps, what can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have two different issues:

For the Hotmail issue:

1. Since we don't want to use this account and use the new one, they are still registered with the old Apple ID. To get them with the new Apple ID, you will need to delete the app and redownload the app with the new Apple ID

For the wrong email entered issue:

1. Go to [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com)
2. Choose manage my account
3. Sign in with the email as it was typed in incorrectly
4. It will say it is not verified and will give you an edit option on the side of the email address
5. Type in the correct email
6. Verify your account for the new Apple ID

I would correct the issue with the new Apple ID first. Then:

1. Go to Settings> iTunes and App Store option.
2. Tap on the Apple ID logged in
3. Choose sign out
4. Sign in with the corrected Apple ID

Then delete the apps and redownload with the new Apple ID

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still want to use my hotmail account, like I said I made a new account thru microsoft using the wrong e-mail, but after I realized that the e-mail was wrong  I found my hotmail login and password, so I dont want anything to do with that microsoft apple Id that kerps popping up, I just want my old hotmail apple id back

Comment: Did you download any apps with that Apple ID?

Comment: And I am logged into my hotmail on my iphone it just doesnt show up when I try to update my apps, the microsoft apple id that I didnt verify keeps popping up

Comment: That's because that account downloaded the apps. They are linked to the incorrect Apple ID. Delete those apps and redownload them with the Hotmail Apple ID

Comment: I deleted those apps the downloaded to the wrong apple id, but when I try to reinstal them the wrong apple id keeps popping up, even though the hotmail account is active and in my icloud the hotmail apple id never comes up just that fake microsoft account that im trying to get rid of, all my apps are deleted that was linked to that fake microsoft account, but the microsoft apple id keeps popping up and I never verified that account

Comment: Did you follow the steps at the end of my answer?

Comment: No I didnt download any apps on dat fake account, the only thi g I did is delete the 6 apps thats the fake id was popping up under, and yes I did follow your steps but I cant access the hotmail id when I try to redownload, the fake microsoft id still keeps popping up even after I deleted the apps

Comment: What account do you see in Settings> iTunes and App Store?

Comment: I saw the microsoft account when I we to settings and app store, I logged out thru my app store thats what I wasnt doing, THANK YOU SIR!!!